# administrar Múltiplos windowsForm SplitContainer

Tags: winforms, vb.net

Tenho múltiplos windowsforms dentro de um SplitContainer, um deles, possúi um ListBox.

Ou seja, fora do SplitContainer, no Form1, tem botão, quando clicar nele, quero adicionar um texto no ListBox dentro do SplitContainer no Form2

Quando clico no button, não acontece nada! < Aqui está o erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Form1 Load:

```
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim form2add As New Form2
    form2add.TopLevel = False
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(form2add)
    form2add.Show()

    Dim form3add As New Form3
    form3add.TopLevel = False
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(form3add)
    form3add.Show()

    Dim form4add As New Form4
    form4add.TopLevel = False
    SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(form4add)
    form4add.Show()
End Sub
```

Button1 code (ERRO está aqui):

```
Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add("Texto a ser adicionado")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que não vai adicionar, você está usando o `Form2.ListBox1.Items.Add` como se fosse um membro estático, ao criar novamente o objeto com `Form2` irá aparecer o item que você definiu. É como se fosse uma pré-adição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para resolver isso você deve criar uma referência ao membro criado, segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
Friend WithEvents form2add As Form
Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     form2add = New Form2() ' Criado a referência semi-pública do objeto '
     form2add.TopLevel = False
     SplitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.Add(form2add)
     form2add.Show()
     ...
```

Ai para adicionar o item para a ListBox, faz o seguinte:

```
form2add.ListBox1.Items.Add("Texto a ser adicionado")
```